# Is there a way to avoid creating a temporary file in R?

Tags: r

I have a database in which VCF files have been inserted as a blob variable. I am able to retrieve it without issue. However, I then need to pass it to some various functions (VariantAnnotation, etc.) that expect a VCF file name. Is there a way to "fake" a file object to pass to these functions if I already have all the data in a character string?

I'm currently writing it out to a file so I can pass it on:

```
#x contains the entire vcf file as a character string

temp_filename = tempfile(fileext = ".vcf")
writeChar(x, temp_filename)
testVcf = readVcf(temp_filename)
unlink(temp_filename)
```

This works ok, but I would like to avoid the unnecessary file I/O if possible.

Comment: looks like readVcf has a lot of flexibility in processing the file into a returned object that you might need.  So the approach might be to look inside the readVcf function and see if there's somewhere it loads the equivalent of your blob (in which case you could just make a version that takes the blob at that point. Or, if readVcf does a lot of clever line by line reading/skipping, see if you can more efficiently get the database to write the blob to disk instead of into R and back out and back in? 

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/VariantAnnotation/versions/1.18.5/topics/readVcf

Comment: You should list what packages you are using. Do these funtions only take character values with path names? Or do they allow you to pass in a connection object?